# databinding button onclick not working

Tags: android, android-databinding

activity_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View" />

        <variable
            name="callback"
            type="com.buscom.ActionCallBack" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/ll_oml"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/grey_50"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="@{(v) -> callback.onClick(v)}"
                android:text="Menu" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

**ActionCallBack.java**

This is the interface I implement in MainActivity

```
public interface ActionCallback { 
    void onClick(View view);
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
    actionCallBack = new ActionCallBack() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            System.out.println("Call onclick method *****");
        }
    }
}
```

When i click on button onClick() method is not evoked, noting is shown in output or no action performed. But is works in the traditional way with onClickListener

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think there is a mistake in your Activity declaration. Anyhow, you are still not setting your callback, as such:

`binding.setCallback(this);`

or

`binding.setCallback(actionCallback);`

Comment: Android Studio looks for binding types. The mistake, which you described is not posible

Comment: @Sergey if you'd pay a bit of attention you would've seen I edited the question because his code did not look OK, that's the error I meant. Not whatever you thought it was

Comment: @Chisko It works now thanks very much. setting `binding.setCallBack(actionCallback);` solved it

Comment: @Chisko you do not need to solve problem while editing a question. This way you can to  confuse community and it make question harder to understand.

Comment: @Sergey could you please clarify in what manner my edit alters the meaning/intention of the question?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue using this:

```
binding.setHandlers(this);
```

I was working in a fragment.

Comment: The setter method depends on the name of your variable in the XML, I suppose yours was 'handlers'